# Dev Express Aspx Gridview Multi-row filter control

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am utilizing the Devexpress aspxGridview control throughout my asp.net web forms application.  Many of the databases that I would like to be able to visual and filter using these controls have a large number of fields in them.  Here is an example below (although this is not the largest field set)

[image]

Does the control provide a way to separate these fields into multiple rows and use a preview field instead of individual columns.  For example something that might look like this.

[image]

Or Even completely horizontal like this.

[image]

I realize this can probably be accomplished fairly successfully using css but based on the markup created by the control it looks like it might be a fairly time consuming task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no proper way to force breaking the ASPxGridView's Header between multiple lines. It is possible to specify the required layout using the use grid's templates (the http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3678, for instance, for keeping header functionality).

However, in this case, it is necessary to implement custom filter editors and force grid filtering programmatically. The built-in columns' headers functionality will be lost.

Probably it would be better to use the external filter for the ASPxGridView:

**Filter Control - External Filter for GridView**

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxFilterControl/FilterBuilder.aspx